# How can I reuse a variable later on in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to capture a user input (textfield + button) and reuse the result later in the program but I don't know how to do that.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var moneyTextField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func convert(_ sender: Any) {
        let convertion:Double = Double(moneyTextField.text!)!
        print(convertion)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "https://www.x-rates.com/calculator/?from=EUR&to=USD&amount=1")!
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url : url)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            data, response, error in
            var rateValue:Double = 0.0;
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            } else {
                if let unwrappedData = data {
                    let dataString = NSString(data: unwrappedData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                    var stringSeperator = "<span class=\"ccOutputRslt\">"
                    if let contentArray = dataString?.components(separatedBy: stringSeperator){
                        if contentArray.count > 0 {
                            stringSeperator = "<span"
                            let newContentArray = contentArray[1].components(separatedBy: stringSeperator)
                            if newContentArray.count > 0 {
                                rateValue = Double(newContentArray[0])!
                                print(newContentArray[0])
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //
            print("Rate is \(rateValue)");

            DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: {
                self.resultLabel.text = "the value of the dollar is " + String(rateValue)
            }
        )}
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

What I want to do is take the `let convertion` and multiply it by `rateValue` at the end of the code. I tried different thing but without any results.

after the advice from Joakim Danielson
I did that :

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var fxRate: Double?

@IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var moneyTextField: UITextField!
@IBAction func convert(_ sender: Any) {



    let convertion:Double = Double(moneyTextField.text!)!
    print(convertion)

    var convertedAmount = 0.0
    if let rate = fxRate, let money = Double(moneyTextField.text) {
        convertedAmount = rate * money
    }
    print(convertedAmount)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    let url = URL(string: "https://www.x-rates.com/calculator/?from=EUR&to=USD&amount=1")!

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url : url)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in
        var rateValue:Double = 0.0;
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        } else {
            if let unwrappedData = data {
                let dataString = NSString(data: unwrappedData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                var stringSeperator = "<span class=\"ccOutputRslt\">"
                if let contentArray = dataString?.components(separatedBy: stringSeperator){
                    if contentArray.count > 0 {
                        stringSeperator = "<span"
                        let newContentArray = contentArray[1].components(separatedBy: stringSeperator)
                        if newContentArray.count > 0 {
                            rateValue = Double(newContentArray[0])!
                            print(newContentArray[0])

                            rateValue = Double(newContentArray[0])!
                            self.fxRate = rateValue
                        }

                    }


                }
            }
        }



        //
        print("Rate is \(rateValue)");

        DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: {
            self.resultLabel.text = "the value of the dollar is " + String(rateValue)

        }
        )}
     task.resume()
    }




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

}

but I have the error : Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Double' with an argument list of type '(String?)' on line 26. Can you please help me? thx!

Comment: This is at least the 3rd time you have posted this same question. Please stop deleting and reposting your questions.

Comment: I know what I m doing ;-) you don t need to remind me. I trying to be more explicit because I didn't get any response. Do you have one for me?

Comment: If you feel like your question isn't clear enough, you should edit it instead of creating a new one.  This still bumps up your question in the list of active questions, so there isn't much benefit to making a new one instead.  Plus, deleting questions can contribute to an automatic question ban if you aren't careful.

Comment: thx for the feedback. I will do that next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a variable outside of your function

```
 var anyVariableYouWantToAccessLater: Double?
```

And use this variable anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're downloading the rate during `viewDidLoad` I am assuming this is what you want to keep.

Add a new property to the class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var fxRate: Double?
    ...
```

In `viewDidLoad` update this property with the downloaded value

```
rateValue = Double(newContentArray[0])!
fxRate = rateValue
```

In the `convert` func (or wherever you want to use the rate)

```
@IBAction func convert(_ sender: Any) {
    var convertedAmount = 0.0
    if let rate = fxRate, let money = Double(moneyTextField.text ?? "0") {
        convertedAmount = rate * money
    }
    print(convertedAmount)
}
```

Comment: hi thank you for your advice. I did that but I have now the error: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Double' with an argument list of type '(String?)' on line 26. can you please have a look? I ve edited my 1st post with your code. Many thx

Comment: It seems to work with: if let rate = fxRate, let money = moneyTextField.text {
            convertedAmount = Double(rate) * Double(money)! I have now only to find a way to update the label

Comment: just change `Double(moneyTextField.text)` to`Double(moneyTextField.text ?? "0")`

Comment: I agree with @PramodKumarSaxena , better to avoid forced unwrapping. I updated my answer.

Comment: it worked! and I was able to update the label. thx to you guys!